# Data structure for buffering encoded audio in android

Tags: android, audio, decoding, blockingqueue

I have TCP client which received audio (encoded) data through socket. I have to keep received data in some buffer and provide to decoder when requested by decoder chunk by chunk. Data is in byte[] and array size can vary. What should I use as buffer to keep the received byte[] chunks. **I know about BlockingQueue but it doesn't provided adding and retrieving N size of byte[].**

Does Java provide any data structure for this purpose, can we use ByteBuffer?

Answer (score 1):

Does your client know how the byte array size varies?
A well known approach (it needs you manage this also at the server side) is to encapsulate the data inside a packet with the following fields: `| TYPE | SIZE | DATA |`
so, supposing the client has an open socket connection and instantiate a DataInputStream (`dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream())`), the client can read the data in a thread which `run` method is something like this:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while(running) {

        int pckType = readPacketType();

        int pckSize = readPacketSize();

        byte[] data = readPacketContent(pckSize);

        // do something with data
        // you can use Semaphore instances in order to maintains a set of permits if needed
    }
}
```

where

```
private int readPacketType() {
    int result = -1;
    byte[] array = new byte[1];
    try {
        dataInputStream.read(array);
        result = (int)array[0];
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        return -1;
    }
    return result;
}

private int readPacketSize() {
    int result = -1;
    byte[] array = new byte[4];
    try {
        dataInputStream.read(array);
        result = ByteBuffer.wrap(array).getInt();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        return -1;
    }
    return result;
}

private byte[] readPacketContent(int contentSize) {
    byte[] result = new byte[contentSize];
    try {
        dataInputStream.read(result);
    } catch (IOException ex) {}
    return result;
}
```

noting that I assigned, for example, 1 byte for the TYPE field and 4 byte for the SIZE field

**EDIT:**
You can use an implementation of the BlockingQueue interface like LinkedBlockingQueue. You can put byte[] of different size and retrieve them coherently (keeping the order and the size). Follows an easy check ;)

```
LinkedBlockingQueue<byte[]> lbq = new LinkedBlockingQueue<byte[]>();
String str1 = "blablabla";
String str2 = "blabla";
try {
    lbq.put(str1.getBytes());
    lbq.put(str2.getBytes());
    lbq.put(str1.getBytes());
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
byte[] b = null;
int size = lbq.size();
for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    try {
        b = lbq.take();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(b.length);
}
```

Comment: I think I couldn't express my problem correctly. I need to know a data structure which I can use to put received chunks (byte[]) until actually start decoding. Once decoding start, I want to pick those chunks(byte[]) and feed to decoder. I can use BlockingQueue but how can I specify byte[] size when read/writing to queue?

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood the issue and still don't understand what can fit your needs since I'd use the BlockingQueue instance and feed it with byte[] (of different size) as single objects

Comment: if I use BlockingQueue<Byte[]>, How can I put different size byte[] arrays via put(object) and what size of byte[] will be returned in take(object) ? @bardi

Comment: `LinkedBlockingQueue<byte[]> lbq = new LinkedBlockingQueue<byte[]>();` `String str1 = "blablabla"; lbq.put(str1.getBytes()); byte[] b1 = null; b1 = lbq.take(); System.out.println(b1.length);`

Comment: yes, I checked with BlockingQueue<byte[]>. we can put different size byte[] in queue and when dequeuing i.e take(), it returns the byte[] in same length n order as entered. Edit your answer and I'll accept. Thanks for help.